# Is there an optimization scheme/algorithm that converges, for this non-convex scenario but with some special properties

Tags: optimization, reference-request, nonconvex

I have a smooth function $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ that is the ratio of two smooth convex functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$. It is known that $f(x)$ has a global minimum, achieved at the unique point $x_0$. Also is known that $f(x)$ has countably many local minima, and function $f(x)$ value at no two local minima, is the same.

Question: Is there any optimization algorithm for this scenario, which converges to the global minimum. I am hoping there is some variant of gradient descent or the likes. Appreciate any references/solutions.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/42424/5038, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/31105/4274, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3122294/14578. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 4):

Despite your claim that these functions have "special properties", the properties you've supplied still leave `f` and `g` extremely general. This means the answers you're going to get must be correspondingly general. If, for instance, you know that `g` is always positive or `f` is quadratic, or `g` is some kind of positive semi-definite matrix, and so on, then you should ask a new question specifying this critical information from the start.

What you're trying to do is convex-convex fractional programming. Schaible's 1976 paper "[Minimization of ratios](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00934101)" explains how such a problem can be transformed into a [quasi-convex problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function)
[image: Schaible 1976]

So you can make this into a quasi-convex problem. That means that you can use bisection to solve the problem to $\epsilon$ tolerance in $\lceil log_2((u-l)/\epsilon)\rceil$ steps where $l$ and $u$ bound the range of the $t$ variable shown above.

Depending on the functions involved, you may be able to use cvxpy to solve the problem. Some examples showing bisection of quasiconvex functions are [here](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/applications/ant_array_min_beamwidth.html) and [here](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/applications/maximise_minimum_SINR_BV4.20.html).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention : f,g are strictly positive. Hope that helps : in case in this light, if it would deserve another answer, please advice accordingly. Also both$f$ and $g$ are quadratic.

Comment: need your permission to proceed if I can post another question, or if you could help on this post itself. Thanks

Comment: sorry both $g$ and $h$ are quadratic and strictly positive. not $f$ as I had mistakenly put in previous comment.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: Does your problem have any constraints?

Comment: None except one parameter in parameter vector is always zero.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: As in, the optimization algorithm has to enforce that? If so, is it (a) a particular element or (b) that any one element must be zero and the rest of the elements can be anything?

Comment: This is not a problem, only one particular element must be zero, so it can be initialized to zero and not do any gradient descent to that element. It is as good as treating that a constant 0. We don't have to enforce. Sorry this is not actually an issue. so no constraints.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and reference Richard. It is very useful

Comment: @Rajesh: If you'd like to open a new question with these constraints specifically stated, I think there may be better answers I can give you. (Leave this general question up, though)

Comment: Posted the new specific question here : https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/31119/13214

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: I was going to work on your question today, but it seems to have disappeared.

Comment: I had deleted this assuming it was not suitable here. Udeleted now : https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/31119/13214