# Minimizing the ratio of two specific non negative quadratic convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonconvex

$F$ is $m\times m$ diagonal, with real non negative elements

$D$ is $n \times m$ complex

$P$ is $n \times 1$ complex

$A$ is $m \times 1$ complex.

Minimize $\Gamma(A)$, with respect to $A$.

$$\Gamma(A) = \frac{m^2(DA-P)^H (DA-P) + (FA)^H(FA)}{A^HA}$$

**It is known** that both numerator and denominator of $\Gamma(A)$ are **convex** and non negative. Also both the terms of the numerator are individually convex and non negative.

Question:  An numerical optimization algorithm to find global minimum.

Apart from a reagular solution, I am also interested in a gradient descent based method if possible as  the matrices are large. Also $m >> n$.

PS : This question is a specific version of [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/31105/13214).

**EDIT** : more known information

No constraints on problem but

1. $\sum P = 0$, I mean sum of elements of matrix $P$ is zero.
2. Diagonal elements of $F$ are not all zeros.
3. Also $P^HP \ne 0$.
4. Rows of $D$ are orthogonal to each other. Also they are linearly independent.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @nicoguaro   An numerical optimization algorithm to find global minimum.

Comment: it can also be a reference request, if a numerical scheme already exists.

Comment: If your objective function is not convex you don't have guaranteed to attain the global minimum.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: This problem has a nice solution if you don't have to divide by $A^HA$. You might want to reflect on whether that's a necessary thing to do.

Comment: @Richard : I had already solved that in case of no denominator, one you take derivative it becomes linear. But  now the denominator is a must. Can the article in your previous answer be used here as it is a ratio of convex functions?